# How to verify order of execution in XUnit Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, xunit.net

I have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public Stream TestStream;

    public WriteToTestStream()
    { ... }
}
```

`WriteToTestStream` writes to the `TestStream`.

I want to write a Unit Test to make sure that

1. `Prop1` and `Prop2` are being set before writing to the `TestStream`
2. The properties should not be accessed once something is written to the `TestStream`.

How can I define a Mock for `WriteToTestStream` in this case?
How can I manipulate local variables from a Mocked function(I can use local variables in the Unit Test to remember when the Stream was written / properties were set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by keeping local state variables and then using Moq's callbacks to track the state, you can `Assert` within the callbacks to ensure the correct state. Here's an example (Albeit in NUnit). I've also assumed that you actually want to test a SUT which uses `Foo` in the correct order (I've called the SUT `Bar` here).

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest
{
    private bool _prop1Set = false;
    private bool _prop2Set = false;
    private Mock<IFoo> _mockFoo;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
        _mockFoo.SetupSet(m => m.Prop1).Callback(i => _prop1Set = true);
        _mockFoo.SetupSet(m => m.Prop2).Callback(s => _prop2Set = true);
        _mockFoo.Setup(m => m.WriteToTestStream())
                .Callback(() => Assert.IsTrue(_prop1Set && _prop2Set));
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureInOrder()
    {
        var sut = new Bar(_mockFoo.Object);
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => sut.DoSomethingInOrder());
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureOutOfOrder()
    {
        var sut = new Bar(_mockFoo.Object);
        Assert.Catch<Exception>(() => sut.DoSomethingOutOfOrder());
    }
}
```

Note that in order to Mock your `Foo` class, methods and properties need to be overridable, e.g. all virtual or with an abstracted interface.

Here's an example of such refactoring:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
    void WriteToTestStream();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    // Surely this is internal implementation
    private Stream TestStream;
    public void WriteToTestStream() { }
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    public Bar(IFoo injectedFoo)
    {
        _foo = injectedFoo;
    }

    public void DoSomethingInOrder()
    {
        _foo.Prop1 = 1;
        _foo.Prop2 = "Baz";
        _foo.WriteToTestStream();
    }

    public void DoSomethingOutOfOrder()
    {
        _foo.WriteToTestStream();
        _foo.Prop2 = "Baz";
        _foo.Prop1 = 1;
    }
}
```

Another way of doing this could be to use [Declan Whelan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223698/314291) [`MoqSequences` extension](https://github.com/dwhelan/Moq-Sequences/), although I must admit I haven't used it yet.

**Edit**

It appears that `MockSequence` (`InSequence`) has [made it into recent versions of `Moq`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moqdisc/TfKpk2oHg88), although this might enforce a very rigid sequence, and also appears to require [MockBehavior.Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9172811/314291):

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest
{
    private Mock<IFoo> _mockFoo;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var seq = new MockSequence();
        _mockFoo.InSequence(seq).SetupSet(m => m.Prop1 = It.IsAny<int>());
        _mockFoo.InSequence(seq).SetupSet(m => m.Prop2 = It.IsAny<string>());
        _mockFoo.InSequence(seq).Setup(m => m.WriteToTestStream());
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureInOrder()
    {
        var sut = new Bar(_mockFoo.Object);
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => sut.DoSomethingInOrder());
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureOutOfOrder()
    {
        var sut = new Bar(_mockFoo.Object);
        Assert.Catch<MockException>(() => sut.DoSomethingOutOfOrder());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart. The solution with Callbacks would work for me. I think there is an issue with InSequence though. I read it doesn't work with the same Mock object. - https://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=291

Comment: It could well be - to be honest, I haven't found many cases where I want to verify the order of calling a dependency's methods (IMO this would usually be white box / implementation detail). However, to provide a sequence of return data, I've generally used the `ReturnsInOrder` extension [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/24/moq-sequences-revisited.aspx/)